# I use the events Calendar Plugin and I want to change some words

Tags: the-events-calendar

Good Morning,

I use Events Calendar for our Website, now I want to change the "Now onwards" and 
"onwards" on top of the page, also the next and previous at the bottom of the event calendar. I already tried to change it with their documentation (and support) but it didn't work. As we are a German business without English business Connections we don't want to have some English text on our page..
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The "Now onwards" string is translated with [_x()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) which is different than __() because it allows context to be added to the string being translated.

Because there is context, you need to use [gettext_with_context](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext_with_context/) instead of gettext.  Here's a simple example based on the one in the WP.org Code Reference:

```
function example_gettext_with_context( $translated, $text ) {
        if ( 'Now' == $text ) {
              $translated = 'Today';
         }

   return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'example_gettext_with_context', 10, 2 );
```

You can find the relavent code in the Events Calendar plugin [here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/the-events-calendar/tags/5.1.1/src/Tribe/Views/V2/Views/Traits/List_Behavior.php#L49) and [here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/the-events-calendar/tags/5.1.1/src/Tribe/Views/V2/Views/Traits/List_Behavior.php#L158)

[The Events Calendar website](https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/change-the-wording-of-any-bit-of-text-or-string/) also has some detailed examples.

Answer (score 0):

For only a couple of words I would use the gettext filter e.g.

```
function wse_text_filter( $translated_text, $untranslated_text ) {
    switch( $untranslated_text ) {

        case 'Now onwards':
          $translated_text = __( 'Now backwards','text_domain' );
        break;

        case 'onwards':
          $translated_text = __( 'Backwards','text_domain' );
        break;

   }
   return $translated_text;
}
add_filter('gettext', 'wse_text_filter', 20, 3);
```

It's hopefully pretty self explanatory, you could also try language switching plugins such as Polyang or WPML.

Comment: Hi, so I inserted this into the functions.php of our website, but it still shows the Now onwards. Am I doing something wrong?