# Changing the words 'Now' & 'onward' to just the single word 'Dates' in The Events Calendar

Tags: the-events-calendar

I am trying to change 'Now onwards' to just 'Dates'. Something similar was done on: [I use the events Calendar Plugin and I want to change some words](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/359171/i-use-the-events-calendar-plugin-and-i-want-to-change-some-words/386027?noredirect=1#comment560259_386027)

When I used Kevin's snippet, from the link above, I could not get it to replace both 'Now' and 'Onwards'.

How can I get it to replace both of those words?

This is what I have so far:

```
function example_gettext_with_context( $translated, $text ) {
if ( 'Now' == $text ) {
      $translated = 'Dates';
 }
   return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'example_gettext_with_context', 10, 2 );
```

I have already tries the plugin "Say What" and that didnt work.

I have also already tried the Events Calendar solution that is posted at: https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/change-the-wording-of-any-bit-of-text-or-string/ But it did not work either

Answer (score 0):

It appears that The Events Calendar has changed "Now Onwards" to "Upcoming" on their own. This problem is now irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know - someone else might want to change it to something different still. But glad this fixed it for you!